# How use postgresql's ANY to access multidimensional array in dynamic query

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, multidimensional-array

I call a postgres function with a  multidimensional array like so:

```
SELECT get_listings(ARRAY[['name:John','grade:1'],['id:5','year:2020']]);
```

The postgresql function has the following signature:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_listings(arr text[]) RETURNS TABLE 
(
    id text,
    tagz text
)
```

Inside the function I have constructed a statement in a loop:

```
select * from (select product_type_id, string_agg(tag, '','') as tags 
from all_tags group by product_type_id) as a 
where tags = any($1[0]) and tags = any($1[1])
```

which is assigned to variable `stmt`;

Now I call

```
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE stmt using arrArgs;
```

where `arrArgs` has earlier been assigned with `arr`;

I get this error:

```
ERROR: op ANY/ALL (array) requires array on right side
```

How can I access the inner array in the `any` function call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostgreSQL has the best and easy function `unnest()` for expanding array elements to a set of rows. For example:

```
SELECT unnest(array[['tagA','tagB'],['tagA','tagB']]);

Result: 

 unnest 
----------
|  tagA  |
|  tagB  |
|  tagC  |
|  tagD  |
```

Then you can use any conditions on the `where` statement.

```
select main.* from 
(
    SELECT unnest(array[['tagA','tagB'],['tagA','tagB']]) as array_data 
) main 
where main.array_data in ('tagA', 'tagD');

Result: 

 array_data 
--------------
|  tagA      |
|  tagD      |
```